Is there a way to write to an Anylogic database with the code?
I'm doing a project in which I use an excel file as database, in the program I have 3 machines, and and the excel file has a column with the machine name and the availability status (boolean value), I imported the database to AnyLogic and I'm able to read the status of each machine but I would like to be able to change the status during runtime and this to be reflected in the database, my question is: Is there a way to write to an Anylogic database with the code? I appreciate your help!
I have tried using some functions to write to a database but AnyLogic is not recognizing them. I have the student version of the software, not the pro.

First: it is not a good idea to do this at runtime. Do it at the end of a run.
Second: yes, check the insertInto() method. Beware of caching though!
